# How can we generate the session token in aws

Tags: command-line, amazon-ec2, aws, amazon-linux, amazon-s3

i have aws access key and secret key with me. i wanted session token to be updated in aws credential file (~/.aws/credentials), how will i get it?

I want them to be generated in command line.

Answer (score 4):

```
$aws sts get-session-token --duration-seconds 129600
```

Here 129600 can be any time you want to specify after which the keys will expire. This command will give the output like below.

```
{
   "Credentials": {
       "SecretAccessKey": "Sb5pXXXXXQY3/qPoL/jUjMyXXXXXuev/0j3vXs",
       "SessionToken": "FQoGZXIvYXdzENv//////////wEaDEeLj11xTbnBk6azRCKsAacCiJK85DSXExJ81GtHrkEyev8eedQcFY4EoM00PsD1FAEMOfzQclVEFsoh9Y4ZHUjgGmCPRUnYCLNc2NnHkadvmI+MT7jRRa1Mo2HA/HYStOOwEyfXFYG91MNj9rVXXXXXXXXA6+7FF6jcxj3cr1U9CDB9hjW+jGq4UgjxXXXXXXXCoIidDjl4Z911zIzP/Q+FYA1R2CUz5Y32EUaMzR+bQvmheUolLOq3wU=",
       "Expiration": "2018-11-14T21:29:56Z",
       "AccessKeyId": "ASIXXXXXXXXZ27X"
   }
}
```

Comment: I wish that you could pipe this output to `aws configure`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` is **not used** when you have *IAM User* access and secret keys.

It's only needed when you use *IAM Role* - either through *[Cross-account access](https://aws.nz/best-practice/cross-account-access/)*, or *[EC2 instance role](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/)*, etc.

Comment: Actually i want them to be used for a distcp command. so without session token its throwing error..

Comment: The error is because you most likely have a session token set in you shell. Unset it and you'll be fine.

Comment: i am completely new to aws. how shd i do that?

Comment: @Vandhana run `env | grep ^AWS_` and update your question with the output. I'll tell you what's wrong then. Also - are you on EC2 instance or on your laptop?

Comment: EC2 instance means? i m working on a server provided for my project. and for the above command i didn't get any output :(

Comment: What is EC2 instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html

Comment: Actually the keys are provided to us from a 3rd party tool, to upload few files. they gave secret key, access key and s3 path. i see aws been installed in my server.for doint distcp from hadoop to aws, i am getting some error as session token is not provided. hope the abov information helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222825/aws-file-upload  same as this question... but i dont see anyone answerd this :|

Answer (score 0):

You can use get-session-token with below parameters.

```
  get-session-token
[--duration-seconds <value>]
[--serial-number <value>]
[--token-code <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html